# How to deal with the security of odd standard fields?

Tags: apex, security, isv

We are using the `Security.stripInaccessible` method to identify fields that don't have the proper DML permission to `insert`, `update` etc. It works good for the most part but it gives us some false positives that we need to handle afterwards.

Here are post `Security.stripInaccessible` checks that we do to identify the inaccessible fields:

```
fieldDescribe.getType() != DisplayType.ADDRESS // Filters out compound address fields
fieldDescribe.isPermissionable() // Filters out (most) system fields and master-detail lookups on the child
!fieldDescribe.isCalculated() // Filters out formula fields
```

I'm fine with these checks since they are dynamic and don't require our intervention. The thing that really bothers me though is the following fields:

- System fields that we have not found a way to identify them using Apex: `LastReferencedDate`, `LastViewedDate`
- The clone field that causes some test cases to fail only when packaging (I can't access this field using the Schema function seems like an internal Salesforce field): `CloneSourceId`
- Standard Contact object checkboxes that are defaulted to hidden by Salesforce I believe even for admins and none of our clients having access to them (Technically not a false positive but still annoying) `HasOptedOutOfFax` `HasOptedOutOfEmail` `DoNotCall`
- I believe enabling Salesforce to Salesforce connection adds these two fields which I also don't know how to filter out: `ConnectionReceivedId` `ConnectionSentId`
- The field that breaks in some subscriber orgs but I cannot find: `CanAllowPortalSelfReg`

Currently, the way we're dealing with this problem is that we maintain a list of "odd" fields and they bypass the security checks function. The problem with this approach is that we have to maintain this list and once in a while deal with service interruption in client orgs.

Ideally, non of our DML calls should have extra fields that aren't being updated but we have a large code base and some dynamic queries grab more than they should.

I'm curious how others are dealing with the issue or if they use something other than `Security.stripInaccessible`. The optimal solution I'm looking for is something that doesn't require SOQL queries to do the CRUD FLS and also doesn't return too many false positives.

Answer (score 3):

How we do this in our app is to determine if a field is required, then use Security.stripInaccessible to remove inaccessible fields, compare it to our list of required fields, and surface an error only if we're missing a required field, otherwise we just continue as normal with the removed fields. Also, as a practical matter, you should generally make new sObject records in a map or list so that you only update fields that you intend to. You could even make a utility class to handle this in a uniform manner.

Comment: Interesting. My concern with this approach is clients saying “the field X didn’t update for no reason” Or when they notice a process wasn’t updating a field that it was supposed to for some time and we have to deal with the consequences and fix it. How often do these happen? As for the construction of a new dml object, that’s somewhat a team effort that each of us need to do sometime in the future.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian Again, we don't allow the process to finish if a required field goes missing. Of course, each app might have different requirements, so what works for us may not work for you.

Comment: Oh you mean ”required” as in required by the process not required on the object itself